# Changing the head of a large Fortran binary file without dealing with the whole body

Tags: io, fortran, binaryfiles

I have a large binary file (~ GB size) generated from a Fortran 90 program. I want to modify something in the head part of the file. The structure of the file is very complicated and contains many different variables, which I want to avoid going into. After reading and re-writing the head, is it possible to "copy and paste" the reminder of the file without knowing its detailed structure? Or even better, can I avoid re-writing the whole file altogether and just make changes on the original file? (Not sure if it matters, but the length of the header will be changed.)

Comment: This won't work if the file has checksums at the end of every record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are changing the length of the header, I think that you have to write a new, revised file.  You could avoid having to "understand" the records after the header by opening the file with stream access and just reading bytes (or perhaps four byte words if the file is a multiple of four bytes) until you reach EOF and copying them to the new file.  But if the file was originally created as sequential access and you want to access it that way in the future, you will have to handle the record length information for the header record(s), including altering the value(s) to be consistent with the changed the length of the record(s).  This record length information is typically a four-byte integer at beginning and end of each record, but it depends on the compiler.